# Android Java syntax error

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm writing a small application using sqlite.
The debugger says that there is a  syntax error.
I've tried But I couldn't find where it is.

> 12-20 14:13:40.353: E/SQLiteLog(2329): (1) near ",": syntax error
>
> SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, String, String[], String, CancellationSignal) line: 1317
> SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(String, String[]) line: 1253
> TemporaryDatabase.EntryGiris(int, String, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) line: 125

Here is the code:

```
public class TemporaryDatabase {
......

    String entryGirisSQL="SELECT "+C_ID
                        +" FROM harcamalar WHERE "+C_YIL+"="
                        +yilsql+","+C_AY+"="+aysql;
    Cursor  cursor=ourDatabase.rawQuery(entryGirisSQL, null);   
    int index=cursor.getColumnIndex(C_ID);
    if(index>=0)
        ourDatabase.update(DB_TABLE, cv, "c_id="+index, null);
    else ourDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
  }

}
```

Comment: [Do I look like a guru?](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Guru_Myth)

Comment: Post only the relavent portion of code for eg: code to which this error is pointing to, otherwise it will be difficult for us to debug

Comment: Oy with the downvotes, it's actually not half bad! The log is there, the code is there (even if you have to look for the query a bit). Chill!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your SQL query.

```
SELECT "+C_ID+" FROM harcamalar WHERE "+C_YIL+"="+yilsql+","+C_AY+"="+aysql;
```

SQL does not support commas as part of the `WHERE` clause. You need to use `AND` and `OR` to combine multiple expressions. Based on what you tried, I assume you want both to be satisfied. Therefore you should use `AND`.

Answer (score 3):

```
getDataHesaplaSQL="SELECT * FROM harcamalar WHERE "+C_YIL+"="+yilsql+","+C_AY+"="+aysql;
```

Hmmm that comma seems out of place in a where clause. Don't you mean `" AND "` or `"OR"`?

Answer (score 2):

```
String entryHesaplaSQL="SELECT c_id FROM harcamalar WHERE "+C_YIL+"="+yilsql+","+C_AY+"="+aysql;
```

is wrong, WHERE clauses don't have , between conditions they have "AND" or "OR"